# Rails many to many relationship confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So im working on a rails app for users to create events (and attend other created events). You can read about the assignment here (for the Odin Project): https://www.theodinproject.com/courses/ruby-on-rails/lessons/associations

Anyways I thought I had understood many to many relationships in rails, but the way i've seen other people write the models is confusing to me.

To me it seems like it should be something like:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :attendances
  has_many :events, through: :attendances
end

class Attendance < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :event
end

class Event < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :users
  has_many :users, through: :attendances
end
```

This makes sense to me because a User can create many events, and an event can have many users attending. (Although attendances is probably the wrong word, maybe invites or something).

But i've seen some weird examples (You can see others source code below on the project) and it seems like they are adding much more to the models and also renaming the source/foreign_key/class_name.

Am I missing something? This still allows a user to "own" an event right? Maybe im mis-understanding how many-to-many works. But this fits at least in my mind of how it should be.

For reference some other models I was seeing was similar to this:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :creator, :class_name => "User"
    has_many :event_attendees, :foreign_key => :attended_event_id
    has_many :attendees, :through => :event_attendees
end

class EventAttendee < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :attendee, :class_name => "User"
    belongs_to :attended_event, :class_name => "Event"
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :created_events, :foreign_key => :creator_id, :class_name => "Event"
    has_many :event_attendees, :foreign_key => :attendee_id
    has_many :attended_events, :through => :event_attendees, :foreign_key => :attendee_id'
end
```

Basically similar things to the above. Im not really sure what this is doing? Or why all the extra is necessary.

Comment: You might want to add some of the "weird examples" to your question - otherwise you're expecting us to go look at them and infer what you think is weird. In any case, what you have looks fine. IMO, it's a little more conventional to name your join model something like `UserEvent`, but I suppose that's personal preference. Also, some might suggest you use HABTM, but I like the way you do it better. Also, there are some different ways to model such things as 'owner', 'invited', 'attending', etc. That's a different discussion altogether.

Comment: I've seen HABTM mentioned...but im not sure what benefit it would give.

Comment: Personally, I don't use HABTM. I just thought I would applaud your `has_many :through` approach.

Comment: I added an example of one of the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example everything according to conventions. Maybe except many-to-many table naming.
`attendances` table has 'user_id' and 'event_id' fields. But in case it could conflict with other fields, or not descriptive enough you could use different keys.

```
belongs_to :creator, :class_name => "User"
```

`belongs_to :creator` by default would look for `Creator` model, so it is needed to specify class name explicitly, like in the provided example.

```
has_many :event_attendees, :foreign_key => :attended_event_id
```

By default foreign key would be `event_id`, so here it is specified explicitly too.

```
has_many :created_events, :foreign_key => :creator_id, :class_name => "Event"
```

By default, rails would look for `user_id` foreign key and `CreatedEvent` model. And these attributes specified explicitly.

You just need to understand what attributes rails provides by default, to change if it is required.

Comment: This makes sense, So what I have now is defined similarly to above, but when making an `invite` and doing something like user.attended_events it gives a `ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughOrderError: Cannot have a has_many :through association 'User#attended_events' which goes through 'User#invites' before the through association is defined.`

So I must be missing something?

Comment: In your code, there are no `attended_events`.
You should do `user.events` if your db structure is correct

Answer (score 1):

ActiveRecord associations default to a class and foreign key with the same name as the association.  The code here is specifically specifying these because they are not the default.